# Help me identifying this font!

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to find what font is the one showed in the picture. I've already search in various sites but I don't find the exact same or at least one very similar.

This font is from a logo that was created for the company I work in. We're trying to develop a new logo of a new product, but of course we want it to look similar to the other products. 
[image]

Comment: There are 2 fonts there, which one are you talking about?

Comment: It's very possible that it isn't a font, just a custom drawing or modified font (Specifically the **A** and **E**) Can you just ask the designer?

Comment: If it is the upper font that you're after, this could be a tough one. Obviously I'm just guessing, but leaving out the most likely customized letters... you're left with `S, Y, T, N, L` (maybe) ...not a lot to base a guess on. `A` and `V` scream custom to me because, without taking a closer look, they seem to be identical, aside from the horizontal line in `A`. There's even the possibility that they were all custom made. `S` looks a bit like it doesn't fit... `Y`is lower case masquerading as uppercase. `T, N and L` look simple enough to be custom made too. `E` could be a stripped down E.

Answer (score 1):

**similar fon**t :-

font name :- **CentreForward** by **The Northern Block**  from https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/northern-block/centreforward